# Unusually long package installation time on RStudio Server Pro Standard on GCP?

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, rstudio-server

If we `install.packages("dplyr")` on a GCP 'RStudio Server Pro Standard' VM, it takes around 3 minutes to install (on instance with 4 cores / 15 gb ram)

This seems unusual, as installation would typicaly take ~20 seconds on a laptop with equivalent specs.

Why so slow, and is there a quick and easy way of speeding this up?

#### Notes

- I use the RStudio Server Pro Standard image from GCP marketplace to start the instance
- Keen to know if there are any 'startup scripts' or similar I can set to run after the instance starts, e.g. to install a collection of commonly used packages

Comment: Are you used to using Windows/Mac on your laptop? On Linux packages typically get compiled every time which takes much longer.

Comment: @Marius I am used to using windows/Mac. I guess this longer install time is expected due to the compilation. I will research how to run a startup script or some other way to install a list of packages automatically on instance creation, if you have any suggestions/pointers, please let me know

Comment: take in consideration that the cores from Google Compute Engine are logical cores while the cores in your laptop are physical and by hyper threading each physical core are two logical cores

Comment: The number of cores will make little/no difference for package install, setup and compilation times. The time to install on an f1-micro will be similar. Your desktop is probably much faster due to already cached objects.

Answer (score 1):

@user5783745 you can also adjust the Makevars to allow multithreaded compilation, which will help speed up compilations.

I followed [this RStudio community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/is-there-a-way-to-enable-multithreading-while-installing-compiling-packages/5519) post, and dropped `MAKEFLAGS = -j4` into `~/.R/Makevars`.

This basically halved the amount of time it took to install `dplyr` from scratch on the RStudio Server Pro Standard for GCP instance I spun up.  (same as yours, 4 vCPU, 15GB ram)